# Unity3D WebGL network download from S3 failing due to missing Origin header + CORS

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, cors, unity-webgl

I'm having some issues trying to download a resource from our S3 CDN.

We appear to have CORS set up properly on S3.

The S3 CORS [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors-troubleshooting.html) states that you need to post the "Origin" header, otherwise it will ignore all of the CORS headers:

> If the header is missing, Amazon S3 doesn't treat the request as a
>   cross-origin request, and doesn't send CORS response headers in the
>   response.

I have tested using curl to ensure that the relevant CORS headers are being returned, and I can see that these are only returned if the "Origin" header is sent.

eg: if I run the following:

```
curl -v -H "Origin: http://localhost" https://cdn.myurl.com/mybucket/mystuff.json
```

I get the following headers returned (as well as a screed of other information):

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, HEAD
```

However, when I DON'T pass the Origin header, those return headers are missing:

```
curl -v https://cdn.myurl.com/mybucket/mystuff.json
```

I'm trying to pull the data down using a UnityWebRequest get request. When I run my application via WebGL I can see an exception when I call request.SendWebRequest()

> Failed to load https://cdn.myurl.com/mybucket/mystuff.json:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:17936' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I can only assume then that the UnityWebRequest isn't sending the "Origin" header.

I can't explicitly set the header, because if I do I get the error:

```
UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
request.SetRequestHeader("Origin", "http://localhost");
```

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot override system-specified headers

I'm quite stuck at this point.

---

UPDATE:

@sideshowbarker mentioned that the Origin header is automatically added by the browser, so that was perhaps a red herring for me.

They also suggested that I need to look at the request headers in my browser tools.  This is what I see when looking at the request from the WebGL application for this particular object in my browser:

[image: Web Request Headers]

There are a couple of points of interest to me here.

- In the Request headers, it has a note that *Provisional headers are shown*.  I assume that means that the browser tools are making their best guess at what headers are being sent?
- The request **is** successful - I get a 200 (success) response code. The content-length header (42) is the correct size that I expect. The game code is just failing based on the missing CORS headers.
- The image shows the 200 response code with the note "(from disk cache)".  I have cleared my cache and re-run this, and the first hit (my code does a retry) does correctly not load from cache, but still fails the CORS test.

The only other spanner in the mix here that I can think of is that we are using CloudFlare in front of the S3 bucket.  I believe that this shouldn't cause issues because it is supposed to forward the CORS headers, but I will do a test bypassing CloudFlare.

Comment: The Origin header is added by browsers, not by any web-application code. So the cause of the error cited in the question isn’t the lack of Origin header in the request. Check the request headers for the request in your browser devtools Network pane.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the CORS policy to the S3 Bucket where you are hosting your game.
[AWS Documentaion.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) That will allow you to then make https calls and Rest API calls etc... It is a bucket setting not a game setting.

Comment: I already have set up my CORS policy in my S3 bucket, and have confirmed that the correct headers are being returned when I call curl while posting an origin header

Comment: Are you hosting your game in the bucket or are you running it locally? If you're running it locally as it looks like above given localhost:// You need to be running it in a web browser without the CORS security. As local host doesn't have CORS enabled

`chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the "HEAD" request to the cors config of Amazon

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "HEAD"
    ],
```